# Metric dynamics in GR

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I'm interested in temporal dynamics of the metric, that is, 
**what is the form of $\frac{d}{dt}g_{\mu\nu}$ which is consistent with Einstein Field Equations.** Solution to source-less ($T_{\mu\nu}=0$) equiation is the asymptotic, stationary solution (as I understand, correct me wrong).
What happens, however, if I start with some non-trivial metric? (say Schwarzschild metric, artificially removing the point-mass at $t=0$). The asymptotic relaxed metric is flat, however what is the dynamics?

Comment: You can't just remove the point mass and expect the result to be physically meaningful as that violates conservation of energy. If you're interested in time dependent vacuum solutions you should start with gravitational waves.

Comment: As @John Rennie mentions, the question (v1) describes an unphysical non-causal situation a la _What happens if the Sun suddenly disappears?_ A mass cannot suddenly disappear. It can at most move away with subluminal speed (massless parts with luminal speed).

Comment: Please elaborate - what is not physical? (preferably extended discussion, article, etc)

Comment: The "disappearing sun" is the example I thought about. I can invent you more  physical examples if this is the problem (massive particle decays to massless counter propagating ones). Suppose I look for solutions only at confined volume without sources. The boundary conditions of the EFE PDE change (with time!) - what is the dynamics within the confined volume?

Comment: There is no point mass in the Schwarzschild solution.

Comment: The solution need not be stationary. You need to start with the metric (at a given "time") and a symmetric 2-tensor (which will be the second fundamental form in space-time of the spacelike slice you start with) that satisfy the constraint equations. The EFE ($Ricci=0$) will determine the solution. To ask about the dynamics is way too general. You need to be more specific.

Comment: The Schwarzschild solution is invalid passed the horizon. This solution is is supposed to be static meaning that the metric does not depend on time. However inside the horizon radius is time and the metric depends on the radius and therefore depends on time. Also, you could not possibly put any mass in the center, because radius is time and the duration of the existence of the central point (aka "singularity") in time is zero.

Comment: Furthermore, there is no "center point" in the Schwarzschild solution. The shape enclosing the singularity is not a point, but an infinitely long straight line.